# JOIN of two subqueries returns 1000x more rows than the total both subqueries combined

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

Im using a Postgres DB via PGAdmin 4.13

For the sake of performance, I'm trying to run two separate selects, and then do an inner join on them. However, it appears to be running every row against every other row, and I'm returning a table that exponentially too large (literally 1000x bigger than either query alone returns.)

First query returns 4320 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM schema_name.table_one WHERE resultset_name LIKE 'My test results%'
```

Second query returns 1080 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM schema_name.table_two WHERE resultset_name LIKE 'My test results%'
```

Join returns 518000 rows :D

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(SELECT * FROM schema_name.table_one WHERE resultset_name LIKE 'My test results%') t1 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM schema_name.table_two WHERE resultset_name LIKE 'My test results%') t2
ON t1.resultset_name = t2.resultset_name
```

Attempting to run a more traditional inner or left join runs forever...

```
SELECT * 
FROM schema_name.table_two
INNER JOIN schema_name.table_one 
ON schema_name.table_two.resultset_name = schema_name.table_one.resultset_name
WHERE schema_name.table_two.resultset_name LIKE 'My test results%'
```

NOTE: That the `WHERE schema_name.table_two.resultset_name LIKE 'My test results%'` requires the `schema_name.table_two.` to be in the WHERE clause, otherwise it errors on an ambiguous column name.

**QUESTION 1**:
Why is the JOIN from two subselects returning so many rows? My intention was to slim down memory use - by returning two smaller tables - and then joining only the data in those tables. Can the query be corrected to do this?

**QUESTION 2**:
If my initial join of two subselects cannot work the way I want it to, how can I filter down the memory use for the traditional join?

EDIT: For additional clarity

[image: Excel description of tables]

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: How many rows exactly were you expecting and why did you expect that number?

Comment: There should be 4320 rows - each row from `table_one` having the appropriately associated experiment run date for the commensurate table_two's data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QUESTION 1: you are joining via resultset_name. I suspect that a lot of rows have the same value in this column. If you have 10 rows in Table_one with resultset_name='My test results 1', and table_two has 20 rows with the same value then the result will have 10x20=200 rows for the same resultset_name.

QUESTION 2: Most database systems do this optimisation themselves (without you having to restructure/rearrange your query). I guess it is because of Q1 that it uses lots of resources.

Are you certain that the join condition is **t1.resultset_name = t2.resultset_name**?

If you can't confirm that this is the case, do some profiling of the resultset_name to find out how many unique values in how many rows, and if the scenario I mentioned in Q1 applies.

Edit: if table_two has the same date for every row for the same resultset_name (or if you are interested in any one of them), then you can reduce table_to two one row per resultset_name before joining to table_one, as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    schema_name.table_one t1 
    
    INNER JOIN
    (   SELECT t2a.resultset_name,
               min(t2a.date_of_experiment) as date_of_experiment
        FROM schema_name.table_two t2a 
        WHERE t2a.resultset_name LIKE 'My test results%'
        GROUP BY t2a.resultset_name) t2
    ON t1.resultset_name = t2.resultset_name
    AND t1.resultset_name LIKE 'My test results%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Each table has data for EVERY experiment run (lots and lots of data.) The `resultset_name` (or `resultset_id`) is the only way to distinguish one experiment from the other. `table_one` has all the experiment data EXCEPT for the date the experiment was run. ´table_two` really only has one column of interest - the date the exp was run. The only common columns between both tables are the `resultset_name` and `resultset_id`. Not sure how to select only those rows from both which are part of experiment "My test results".

Comment: ok, but does table_two have multiple rows for the same resultset_name? if yes, then the scenario I mentioned applies. When this happens, do different table_two rows (for the same resultset_name) have different 'dates' (date the exp was run)?

Comment: Hi. Yes. See the example I added to the question. So while the 'resultset_name' and 'resultset_id' are the same for all rows, the `aquireddate` will be different for each row. The ORDER should be the same for each table. I.e. 0 and 261 match. 1 and 262 match, etc.

Comment: In your expected results, think about why you didn't join row 0 of table1 with row 265 of table2. Perhaps, in your mind these are ordered, and they should be associated 1 by 1 in the order they appear, but a database table needs a column to order it by and there is nothing ordering row 0 ahead of row 1 in table1. so my solution simply chooses the earliest acquireddate for the experiment and associates it with all test results.